# CDI: 2 Producers with different qualifiers

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I have 2 producer-methods, one has only 1 qualifier and one has 2 qualifiers, the one from the first producer and an additional one:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyProducer {

  @Produces
  @Qualifier1
  MyBean produce1(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    ...
  }

  @Produces
  @Qualifier1
  @Qualifier2
  MyBean produce2(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If I try to `@Inject` MyBean with both qualifiers, everything works fine, `produce2` is called. But when injecting MyBean with only `@Qualifier1`, I get an `AmbiguousResolutionException`. In my opinion, `produce2` should only be called when injection point has both qualifiers. Why isn't that the case and what can I do to make it work?

Unfortunately I can not change producer-method 1, because it is in a library. The basic plan is to call my own producer if the injection point has my additional qualifier and if not, call the one from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the observed behavior is clearly specified in CDI 2.0, ch.2.3.4 "Specifying qualifiers of an injected field":

> A bean may only be injected to an injection point if it has all the qualifiers of the injection point.

Assuming an injection point:

```java
@Inject @Qualifier1 MyBean myBean;
```

Then the beans produced by both `produce1` and `produce1` "*have all the qualifiers of the injection point*", i.e. `@Qualifier1`, so both are eligible for injection there, resulting in the `AmbiguousResolutionException`.

In fact, the spec gives an example exactly as the one in the question in ch.2.3.6 "Repeating qualifiers".

---

So what can you do?

For starters, do you really need to qualify `produce2` with `@Qualifier1`? If you have no good reason, just drop `@Qualifier1` from `produce2` and you are done - injection points with `@Qualifier1` select `MyBean` from the library, injection points with `@Qualifier2` select the one from your code. **Your injection points cannot have both `@Qualifier1` and `@Qualifier2`.**

If you still want to inject `MyBean` from `produce2` to injection points that have **both `@Qualifier1` and `@Qualifier2`**, you can still do it [DISCLAIMER: Haven't actually tried this, it will probably need tweaking]. It's a bit more involved: You have to write a portable extension, which is not a hard thing at all. Brief implementation points:

- The `producer2` must be annotated **ONLY** with `@Qualifier2`
- In you extension, observe the [`ProcessInjectionPoint`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/ProcessInjectionPoint.html) event
- If `event.getInjectionPoint().getQualifiers()` contains both `@Qualifier1` and `@Qualifier2`

  - Use `event.configureInjectionPoint().qualifiers(...)` to remove `@Qualifier1` from the set of qualifiers.

The effect is that you remove the `@Qualifier1` when it is present together with `@Qualifier2` at runtime.

Comment: I'll implement proposed solution 1...it is not really needed to have both qualifiers. Thanks!